# Message broker exception handling in session transacted consumer or producer

Tags: java, spring-boot, jms, microservices, saga

I want to use [SAGA](https://microservices.io/patterns/data/saga.html) pattern in my Spring Boot Microservices. For example in order of customer, when the order created, an event like `OrderCreatedEvent` produced and then in customer microservice the listener on `OrderCreatedEvent` Update the customer credit and produce `CreditUpdateEvent` and ... .

I use session transacted `JmsTemplate` for event producing. In javadoc of [`JmsTemplate`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jms/support/JmsAccessor.html#setSessionTransacted-boolean-)  said that the JMS transaction commited after the main transaction:

> This has the effect of a local JMS transaction being managed alongside the main transaction (which might be a native JDBC transaction), with the JMS transaction committing right after the main transaction.

Now My question is how can I handle below scenario:

The main transaction committed (for example order recored committed) and system was unable to commit the JMS transaction (for any reason).

I want to use SAGA instead of two phase commit but I think just SAGA move the problem from order and customer service to order service and JMS provider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SAGA](https://microservices.io/patterns/data/saga.html) hints the issue:

> There are also the following issues to address:
>
> ...
>
> - In order to be reliable, a service must atomically update its database *and* publish an event. It cannot use the traditional mechanism of a distributed transaction that spans the database and the message broker. Instead, it must use one of the patterns listed below.
>
> ...
>
> The following patterns are ways to atomically update state and publish events:
>
> - Event sourcing
> - Application events
> - Database triggers
> - Transaction log tailing

[Event Sourcing](https://microservices.io/patterns/data/event-sourcing.html) is special in this list as it brings radical change on how your system stores and processes data. Usually, systems store only the current state of the entities. Some systems add explicit support for historical states with validity periods and/or [bitemporal data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitemporal_Modeling).

Systems which are based on Event Sourcing store the sequence of events instead of entity state in a way that allows it to reconstruct the state from events. There is only one transactional resource to maintain - event store - so there is no need to coordinate transactions.

Other patterns in the list avoid the issue of transaction coordination by requiring the event producer code to commit all changes - both entities state and events (as entities) - to the single data store. Then a dedicated, but separate mechanism - event publisher - is implemented to fetch the events from the data store and publish them to the event consumers.

Event publisher would need to keep the track of published / unpublished events which usually brings back the problem of coordinated transactions. That's were the idempotency of the event consumers comes to light. Event publisher will replay events from the last known position while consumers will ignore duplicates.

You may also reverse the active / passive aspects of the event producer and event consumer. Event producer stores entities state and events (as entities) to the single data store and provides an endpoint which allows event consumer to access event streams. Each event consumer keeps track of processed / unprocessed events - which it needs to do anyway for idempotency reasons - but only for event streams it is interested about. A really good explanation of this approach is given in the book [REST in Practice](https://restinpractice.com/book/book.html) - chapters 7 and 8.

Answer (score 0):

With SAGA you would like to split or reorder your transaction (tx) steps in 3 phases:

1. Tx steps for which you can have a compensating action. For each T1..N you have a
   C1..N
2. Tx steps that cannot be compensating. If they fail then you trigger previously
   defined C1..N
3. Retriable Tx steps that always succeed.

SAGAs are not ACID, only ACD. You need to implement yourself isolation, to prevent dirty reads. Usually with a locking.

Why SAGA? To avoid synchronous runtime coupling and pour availability. You wait for the last participant to commit.

It's quite a hefty price to pay.

The chance is small but still you can end up with inconsistent events that might be used to source an aggregate.